# How to make @query to criteria query

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.example.demo.dto.ListOfJobPostAppliedBySeeker("
        + "t2.jobpost_id AS jobpost_id, "
        + "t2.address AS address, "
        + "t2.experience_required AS experience_required, "
        + "t2.education_qualification AS education_qualification, "
        + "t2.job_category AS job_category, "
        + "t2.job_title AS job_title, "
        + "t2.job_location AS job_location, "
        + "t2.last_date AS last_date, "
        + "t2.recruiter_id AS recruiter_id, "
        + "t2.qualification AS qualification, "
        + "t2.salary_range_2 AS salary_range_2, "
        + "t2.vacancies AS vacancies, "
        + "t2.website AS website, "
        + "t2.is_applied AS is_applied, "
        + "t1.job_apply_id AS job_apply_id, "
        + "t1.seeker_id AS seeker_id, "
        + "t1.seeker_status AS seeker_status, "
        + "t1.recruiter_status AS recruiter_status, "
        + "t1.jobapply_at AS jobapply_at, "
        + "t1.updated_at AS updated_at) "
        + "FROM JobApply t1 "
        + "LEFT JOIN JobPost t2 ON t1.jobpost_id = t2.jobpost_id where seeker_id = :seeker_id")
public List<ListOfJobPostAppliedBySeeker> getSeekerJobs(@Param("seeker_id") Integer seeker_id);
```

how to make the above query as criteria query and make it short and optimized. I would like to make this query shorter and more efficient. I know that I can use the WHERE clause to specify multiple conditions, but I am not sure how to do this in a way that is both short and efficient.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What makes you think a criteria api is shorter? For starters remove te aliasses, you don't need them, second write a proper JPQL join (without the ON as that will be inferred from the JPA model).